# problem with nested while loops in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, nested

I have 2 lists of names, `names_1` and `names_2`, they are both of the same length (1000), no list has duplicate names, each list contains 1000 unique names, but some names appear in both lists, I want to isolate the names that appear in both lists in a third list `dup_names` and remove them from the original lists, I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
dup_names=[]
m=len(names_1)
i=0
k=0
COMPARED=[]
while i<m:
    while k<m:
        COMPARED.append((i,k))
        if names_1[i]==names_2[k]:
            dup_names.append(names_1[i])
            names_1[i:i+1]=[]
            names_2[k:k+1]=[]
            m=m-1
            k=0
        else:
            k=k+1
    i=i+1

for i_k_pair in COMPARED:
    print(i_k_pair)

print('len(COMPARED) =',len(COMPARED))
print('len(dup_names) =',len(dup_names))
print('len(names_1) =',len(names_1))
print('len(names_1) =',len(names_2))
```

I created the "COMPARED" list to check what `(i,k)` values got compared to each other, the output was:

```
(0,0)
(0,1)
.
.
.
(0,999)
len(COMPARED) = 1000
len(dup_names) = 0
len(names_1) = 1000
len(names_2) = 1000
```

from the i_k_pairs that got printed, I see that it only compaired the 1st name in `names_1` `(i=0)` to all names in `names_2`, since `len(dup_names) = 0`, `len(names_1) = 1000` and `len(names_2) = 1000`, I expext that `len(COMPARED) = 1000000` but it looks like the is a problem with the outed loop, can anyone please explain what's wrong to me?!?!

I know that I can do the job with the following code:

```
dup_names=[]
for i in range(len(names_1)):
    for k in range(len(names_2)):
        if names_1[i]==names_2[k]:
            dup_names.append(names_1[i])

new_names_1=[]
new_names_2=[]
for n in range(len(names_1)):
    s1=0
    s2=0
    for m in range(len(dup_names)):
        if names_1[n]==dup_names[m]:
            s1=1
        if names_2[n]==dup_names[m]:
            s2=1
    if s1==0:
        new_names_1.append(names_1[n])
    if s2==0:
        new_names_2.append(names_2[n])

names_1=new_names_1
names_2=new_names_2

del new_names_1,new_names_2
```

I tried this code and it worked just fine, but what's really puzzling me is:
what's wrong with the first code???
why the outer while loop didn't work?!
is there a problem with nested while loops in Python?

Comment: You could consider the `set` that's handy - find the common items from two lists using set().intersection()

Comment: @jwjhdev this deletes only 1 record in the table, the ith record

Comment: instead of using this: `names_1[i:i+1]=[]`, you should probably use `names.pop(i)`. Also, there is definitely nothing wrong with nested while loops in python. Any time you think "the language is broken" you should go outside for some fresh air :)

Comment: Why do you ask for a solution with two while loops, when you have a working one with for-loops? What's wrong with them?

Comment: @ Daniel Hao thank you, this is a very good idea, but I want to understand what's wrong with the nested while loops, and why they aren't working properly

Comment: Could you add comments to the first part, so that we can see what you wanted it to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is comparing the two lists for duplicates and never compares anything already compared in names_1. I think there might be a well optimized one for this. If you wanna compare the two lists len(names_1) times len(names_2) better avoid removing elements from names_1 and names_2. The reason your code didn't work is, your code was not resetting i=0 to start the names_1 from the beginning after the second while loop.

```
dup_names=[]
names_1=["a","b","c","d","e"]
names_2=["f","g","h","a","d"]
m=len(names_1)
n=len(names_2)
i=0
k=0
COMPARED=[]
while i<m:
    matched_any = False
    while k<n:
        COMPARED.append((i,k))
        if names_1[i]==names_2[k]:
            dup_names.append(names_1[i])
            names_1[i:i+1]=[]
            names_2[k:k+1]=[]
            matched_any = True
            break
        else:
            k=k+1
    i=0
    k=0
    if not matched_any:
        names_1[i:i+1]=[]
    m=len(names_1)
    n=len(names_2)

for i_k_pair in COMPARED:
    print(i_k_pair)

print('len(COMPARED) =',len(COMPARED))
print('len(dup_names) =',len(dup_names))
print('len(names_1) =',len(names_1))
print('len(names_1) =',len(names_2))
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Pythonic approach and set for solving your problem.

```
x = ["C++", "C", "Python"]
y = ["Java", "C"]
z = set(x).intersection(set(y))
x = [elt for elt in x if elt not in z]
y = [elt for elt in y if elt not in z]
```

Comment: @ThomasKlinger But it is not a solution, because it doesn't answer the question. OP has acknowledged there are other (better) ways to do this. The question was "help me understand why *this* code doesn't work", not "gimme t3h codez"